Unable to assign role to service account using REST API on GCP
I am using GCP (cloud resource manager) REST API to assign roles/editor to one of the service account that I created using the IAM service (https://iam.googleapis.com) REST API. But the API is returning 400 Bad Request with following response body:
{
    "error": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
        "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
        "details": [
            {
                "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloudresourcemanager.v1.ProjectIamPolicyError",
                "type": "SOLO_REQUIRE_TOS_ACCEPTOR",
                "role": "roles/owner"
            }
        ]
    }
}

I am using following payload:
{
    "policy": {
        "bindings": [
            {
                "role": "roles/editor",
                "members": [
                    "serviceAccount:[service-account-name]@[project-id].iam.gserviceaccount.com"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}


@  Shashank Shekhar  Did you have time to check my answer? It helped you to solve your problem?  If not, I am happy to assist further. Could you please have a look at this doc and accordingly proceed.

The error “SOLO_REQUIRE_TOS_ACCEPTOR” suggests that there could be a TOS that requires acceptance”
Your project has a setting that makes it a requirement for the users who have owner-level privileges of the system including the roles like roles/editor to accept the GCP Terms of service.
As per this official  document

If the project is not part of an organization, there must be at least
one owner who has accepted the Terms of Service (ToS) agreement in the
policy. Calling setIamPolicy() to remove the last ToS-accepted owner
from the policy will fail. This restriction also applies to legacy
projects that no longer have owners who have accepted the ToS. Edits
to IAM policies will be rejected until the lack of a ToS-accepting
owner is rectified. If the project is part of an organization, you can
remove all owners, potentially making the organization inaccessible.

AS per this Githhub link

The
documentation
says that it is not possible to grant the owner role through gcloud or
the Cloud IAM API. Owners can only be added through the GCP Console.

